# Export MySQL tables into Microsoft SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have an existing database in MySQL, now I need to export that database and import it into MS SQL management.

I tried generating the SQL, and executing in MS SQL Management Studio but it has errors.

anyone a clue how to import?

edit:

in phpmyadmin I selected the tables I wanted, went to export, exported as SQL. 
in MSSQLMS selected created database>execute query. pasted the SQL file contents, executed it. result= loads of syntax errors

Comment: @Larnu edited it

Comment: Download and use the [SQL Server Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/getting-started-with-ssma-for-mysql-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-2017). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/converting-mysql-databases-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-2017) is a link to the steps to follow for the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert MySQL database objects, you first select the objects that you want to convert, and then have SSMA perform the conversion. To view output messages during the conversion, on the View menu, select Output.

To convert MySQL objects to SQL Server

1. In MySQL Metadata Explorer, expand the MySQL server, and then expand Databases.
2. Select objects to convert :

To convert all schemas, select the check box next to Databases.

To convert or omit a database, select the check box next to the Database name.

To convert or omit a category of objects, expand a schema, and then select or clear the check box next to the category.

To convert or omit individual objects, expand the category folder, and then select or clear the check box next to the object.

3. To convert all selected objects, right-click Databases and select Convert Schema.

You can also convert individual objects or categories of objects by right-clicking the object or its parent folder, and then selecting Convert Schema.